# 1990s sci Fi anthology TV series

Tags: story-identification, tv

Trying to remember name of show.  It was centered around an unnamed city.  Episodes include having a clone.  Changing physical sex to see and try understanding what living like the opposite gender is like.  Another has to do with a walled off community outside the city.  Like 50 years ago, some folks thought the world would end.  They set up their survivalist compound.  It is run by robots.  Main character a kid living there.  They each have a dorm room, very regimented life.  Teachers and principal are robots.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Mirror_(TV_series)?

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like [Welcome to Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Welcome_to_Paradox_episodes).

> Episode 6 - "*A wealthy old man has himself cloned so that he can
>   transplant his brain into younger versions of himself. This would
>   insure him perpetual youth and perhaps eternal life. His life gets an
>   unexpected turn when the target clone begins to realize who he is and
>   what he was created for.*"

> Episode 11 - "*Technology has enabled the populace of Betaville to
>   change ones sex as easily as changing ones clothes. So when Cleo
>   Lawson finds that her husband is a philanderer she takes the
>   opportunity to change her sex as a means to understanding what it is
>   to be a man, and perhaps why her husband is the way he is."*

> Episode 8 - *"Hemeac is a student at a school run entirely by
>   machines. Computer controlled androids teach the students mind
>   expanding educational material as well as mechanical precision and
>   computer logic. Unfortunately the Dean of Students is breaking down
>   thus forcing Hemeac to react beyond his learning, but is the time to
>   act too late?"*

Comment: That was it.  Thanks!

Comment: @CrystalWalker - Awesome. Don't forget to press the "accepted" tick on the left hand side of the answer.

Comment: I've been looking for this for years, thanks for the episode synopsis!